# DB design little or too much data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I'm currently working on a little project that uses MySQL. However I'm struggling with the database design. Currently I've come up with 2 designs, one stores more data but is actually the way I want it to be, however this way makes it really hard to work with the data. The other way is I think more basic and simplifies a lot of things but stores less data.

**Design 1**

[image]

Example data items table

| id | description | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2021-04-17 17:30:00 |
| 2 | Bike | 2021-04-17 17:30:00 |

Example data user_items table

| id | user_id | item_id | time_achieved |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-17 17:30:04 |
| 2 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-17 17:30:03 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-17 17:30:17 |
| 4 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-17 17:30:22 |
| 5 | 1 | 1 | 2021-04-17 17:30:34 |
| 6 | 1 | 2 | 2021-04-17 17:30:42 |
| 7 | 1 | 2 | 2021-04-17 17:30:54 |

**Design 2**

[image]

Example data items table

| id | description | time_created |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Car | 2021-04-17 17:30:00 |
| 2 | Bike | 2021-04-17 17:30:00 |

Example data user_items table

| id | user_id | item_id | count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 5 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 2 |

Basically we have items that can be anything, they include a description to specify what they actually are. A user can collect items (a lot). These are stored in the user_items table which contains a FK user_id and item_id to the users and items table. The users table is left out for simplicity.

As you can see design 1 stores a lot more rows for the user_items table, this allows us to add more information (time_achieved and more) per item that a user achieved. However this results in more rows and  probably a harder time queriyng. Design 2 on the other hand simply adds a count column to determine how many items the user has, but this is very limiting because we cannot add more data (achieved time..) per user_item.

I'm not sure if design 1 is the right and only design for what we want to achieve. Basically we really want to store additional metadata per user_item but I just don't know if this is the right design since it quickly fills up the database. Does anyone have a suggestion/idea for an alternative design which stores less data than design 1 but still allows to add more info per user_item?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is premature optimisation. Choose the design that stores the data you need *(you either need the time_achieved meta data or your don't)*.  Then optimise for storage constraints once you can demonstrate they exist *(this database is still tiny, at 20bytes per row in option 1, you'll need **50 million rows** just to reach 1GB, which is still small enough to reside **In Memory**)*.

Comment: If that is a many-to-many mapping between `users` and `items`, see this for optimization:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table

Answer (score -1):

Does anyone have a suggestion/idea for an alternative design which stores less data than design 1 but still allows to add more info per user_item?

Design 1 should work.

This design will also work but quickly fills up, more efficient.
id, item_id,Item_des,Item_qty,user_id,username,time_created all in one table.
some of the values will be repeated.

Comment: Repeating username and ItemDescription in the user_items table is a straight up dumb idea. This will be a transactional (OLTP) database, not an analytical (OLAP) database, there is no sane reason to denormalise. Also, storing those strings repeatedly would likely INCREASE the storage footprint, not decrease it.

Comment: The question was "have a suggestion/idea for an alternative design which stores less data than design 1 but still allows to add more info per user_item?", regardless of OLAP or OLTP, user has to determine which is best for them.

Comment: I have already specified design 1 will work. Have any issues with that?